# Multiple row text input with simple_form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form

I have this form:

```
<%= simple_form_for @article do |m| %>
  <%= m.simple_fields_for :article_comment do |p| %>

    <%= p.error_notification %>

    <%= p.input :article_id, as: :hidden, input_html: {value: @article.id} %>
      <div class="form-inputs">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-2 col-md-offset-1">
            <%= p.label 'What do you think?', :class => 'indexsubtext' %>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-9">
            <%= p.input :comment, label: false, autofocus: true, :input_html => {:style=> 'width: 100%', :rows => 5, class: 'response-project'} %>
          </div>
```

I want the input box to show 5 rows, but it only shows 1. How do I force it to provide 5?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

By default, `simple_form` will choose the element based on the type in your database. If `comment` is of type `string` (rather than `text`), it will use an `input` field, which does not have a `rows` attribute.

Try adding an `as: :text` option. This will force the element to a `textarea`:

```
<%= p.input :comment, label: false, as: :text, autofocus: true, :input_html => {:style => 'width: 100%', :rows => 5, class: 'response-project'} %>
```

This may solve your problem as it did for [this guy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30638066/981183).